# Safari browser doesn't play movie specified in HTML5 Video tag

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

I have a video tag used in one of my views

```
<video 
  id="Video1_@Model.Id" width="80%" onerror="failed(event)"
  controls="true" autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item"
  type="video/mp4 src="filepath" </video>
```

and I am able to play the video in ie and chrome. Where as the requirement is the video should be playable in ipad and iphone. But I couldn't play it in mobile devices and as well as safari desktop.

When I am testing in ipad, the video widget loads with play button, when I click on play button, it doesn't respond.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: 1. does the desktop safari say annoying in the js console - 2. can QUICKTIME play the video if you give it the url - 3. only then go the iPad.

Comment: What file format? What desktop Safari inspector say when you click?

Comment: File format is mp4. It is directly going to fall back message when I click on Video button

Comment: I have installed QUICKTIME, now it is not going to fall back message but a play button appears on desktop Safari too, but it doesn't play the video